# Resizing a Path2D shape when user clicks and drags

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, shapes

So, I have a program that adds a square to a JPanel and lets the user drag the shape around the panel. What I want to do is be able to click on the bottom-right corner of the shape and resize it as the user drags it. I'm kind of stuck on how to do this. I know that as the user drags it will need to recalculate the rectangle's length and width to make the bottom right corner match where the mouse is. But how can I detect a click on the bottom right edge of the rectangle? Thanks for any help.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class UMLEditor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new UMLWindow();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(30, 30, 1000, 700);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class UMLWindow extends JFrame {
    Shapes shapeList = new Shapes();
    Panel panel;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UMLWindow() {
        addMenus();
        panel = new Panel();
    }

    public void addMenus() {

        getContentPane().add(shapeList);

        setTitle("UML Editior");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        shapeList.addSquare(100, 100);
    }

    public void loadFile() {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));

        int r = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        }
    }
}

// Shapes class, used to draw the shapes on the panel
// as well as implements the MouseListener for dragging
class Shapes extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Path2D> shapes = new ArrayList<Path2D>();
    int currentIndex;

    public Shapes() {
        MyMouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
        addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);
        addMouseMotionListener(myMouseAdapter);
    }

    public void addSquare(int width, int height) {
        Path2D rect2 = new Path2D.Double();
        rect2.append(new Rectangle(getWidth() / 2 - width / 2, getHeight() / 2
                - height / 2, width, height), true);

        shapes.add(rect2);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        for (Path2D shape : shapes) {
            g2.draw(shape);
        }
    }

    class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
        private boolean pressed = false;
        private Point point;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                return;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++) {
                if (shapes.get(i) != null
                        && shapes.get(i).contains(e.getPoint())) {
                    currentIndex = i;
                    pressed = true;
                    this.point = e.getPoint();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (pressed) {
                int deltaX = e.getX() - point.x;
                int deltaY = e.getY() - point.y;
                shapes.get(currentIndex).transform(
                        AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(deltaX, deltaY));
                point = e.getPoint();
                repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            pressed = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is doing exactly what OP needs: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Resizeashape.htm

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a couple of things back in the day that might be helpful to you

To start, [AreaManager (http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/)](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/) This is kind of what you want, in that it's dealing with Shapes (*Area*'s, actually). There's a dragger class which uses mouse drag, and a resizer class that uses the mouse wheel. But this isn't exactly the user interface you've described.

That user interface for doing changing the cursor and resizing based on the type of cursor and the mouse drag is in [Draggable in http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/drag/](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/drag/). Draggable works with Components that are contained in Containers with the layoutmanager turned off. But it should be not so complicated to adapt to your purposes